# pass "this" class type as a parameter in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to create a common method for all classes, --->

```
RestMethods.ClearAllStaticValues(this);
```

so here I am passing this as a argument, which is a class reference. 
But how can i catch this in my method definition, in which I am processing that class fields (using reflection), currently I am doing that in my same class. The code below--->

```
var varList = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).ToList();
varList.Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(Int32)).ToList().ForEach(x => x.SetValue(this, 0));
```

note: I don't wanna use it like this--->

```
Class A
{
     RestMethods.ClearAllStaticValues(this);
}
```

& method definition--->

```
RestMethods.ClearAllStaticValues(A args);
```

because it will class specific.

Comment: `arList.Select(x => x)` seems pretty unnecessary...

Comment: @Ed S. : this is not my point, i am asking how to pass class ref in method definition ???

Comment: Yes, I know, just an observation.  That's why I left a comment and not an answer. I can't imagine you're in favor of code that does nothing at all.  The whole thing seems strange in general.

Comment: I am guessing that this is going to be fairly slow. You are only doing this for Int32 objects and setting them to 0, (which may not be classified as 'Empty') .

Comment: ok, i'll correct this, but right now if u hv an answer thn put it.

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish "clearing of static variables". Why do you want to do this in that way?

Comment: @Mare Infinitus: can u give me a hint about any of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably just pass a `Type`:

```
public static void ClearAllStaticValues(Type t)
{
    var varList = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    varList.Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(Int32)).ToList().ForEach(x => x.SetValue(null, 0)); 
}
```

Call it like this:

```
public class A
{
    public static void Clear()
    {
        //static member 
        RestMethods.ClearAllStaticValues(typeof(A));
    }
    public void ClearInstance()
    {
        //instance member
        RestMethods.ClearAllStaticValues(GetType());
    }
}
```

Here is a demo: http://ideone.com/oYQh5X

Comment: & @zespri : `varList.Where(x => x.FieldType =....` syntax error.
varList does not contain any def for Where

Comment: @ashok_damani I copied that one from your post, just use whatever you had before and was working (just change `this.GetType()` to `t`)

Comment: that was `this.Where`, which does not means, but in ur code u are using `Type` instead of `this`, so

Comment: @ashok_damani: Don't forget to import namespaces you need. In this case it's `using System.Linq`

Answer (score 0):

This method of clearing a static int is slow. It is a creative way to remove all integer values from a class, but by the time you introduce all the other object types you wish to clear, this will get even slower.

My test runs this process 50,000 times, so neither are "slow" in essence, but comparatively your method is approx. 700X slower then the traditional method.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        {
            HasStaticObjects hso1 = new HasStaticObjects();
            ClearAllStaticValues(hso1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Clear Generic Static Values: \n" + sw.Elapsed);

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        {
            HasStaticObjects hso2 = new HasStaticObjects();
            hso2.ClearStaticValues();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Clear Static Values: \n" + sw.Elapsed);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void ClearAllStaticValues<T>(T currentClass)
    {
        var varList = currentClass.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).ToList();
        varList.Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(Int32)).ToList().ForEach(x => x.SetValue(null, 0));
        varList.Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(string)).ToList().ForEach(x => x.SetValue(null, ""));
    }
}

class HasStaticObjects
{
    private static int A, B, C;
    private static string D, E, F;
    public HasStaticObjects()
    {
        A = 1;
        B = 2;
        C = 3;
        D = "Hi";
        E = "Good";
        F = "Fast";
    }
    public void ClearStaticValues()
    {
        A = 0;
        B = 0;
        C = 0;
        D = "";
        E = "";
        F = "";
    }
```

Other cases that you need to accept will be times such as when an object contains no integers, or no strings and how will your method's performance be affected by that??

In the test remove the 3 string variables from the `HasStaticObjects` class and you will see that your method will still take time to find strings even though none exist.

Comment: yape !, u r right @Jastill
but wat about if u hv 10 pages each contains 20 static variables & u want to clear all of them each time ?

Comment: that's y i'v chosen that way

Comment: 10 classes with 20 different static variables, using 5 different types, you are looking at a VERY slow process there. Now what happens if your static is NOT a base type?? how will you compensate for that.

This is why each class should have its own clearing method, which can come from a base type, which means you could iterate through all your classes by the base type and call the base method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using reflection, use an interface:

```
interface ClearValues
{
    void ClearStaticValues();
}
class AnyClass : ClearValues
{
    private static int A, B, C;
    public void ClearStaticValues()
    {
        A = 0;
        B = 0;
        C = 0;
    }
}
```

Now have all your objects derive that interface and then you can call  `.ClearStaticValues()`.

This allows you to tailor your `ClearStaticValues` method for each class.